# jQuery/PHP : How to return upload file information properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using the jquery plugin jquery.filer, when I try the upload file on their example on their website http://filer.grandesign.md/ it gives me a return of value like this.

```
{
"files": [
    "..\/uploads\/dK079QrL2g.docx"
],
"metas": [
    {
        "date": "Tue, 07 Feb 2017 06:12:40 +0000",
        "extension": "docx",
        "file": "..\/uploads\/dK079QrL2g.docx",
        "name": "dK079QrL2g.docx",
        "old_name": "Cover letter - Copy.docx",
        "replaced": false,
        "size": 16720,
        "size2": "16.33 KB",
        "type": [
            "application",
            "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

However, after I implement, the output that I got on my website  looks like not same? What is the difference between of this and above?

```
 Array
(
[files] => Array
    (
        [0] => uploads/iD2eBCwStA.docx
    )

[metas] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => Tue, 07 Feb 2017 07:57:03 +0100
                [extension] => docx
                [file] => uploads/iD2eBCwStA.docx
                [name] => iD2eBCwStA.docx
                [old_name] => Cover letter - Copy.docx
                [replaced] => 
                [size] => 16720
                [size2] => 16.33 KB
                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => application
                        [1] => vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Here is my JS

```
//filter uploader
$('#files').filer({
    showThumbs: true,
    maxSize : 25,
    fileMaxSize : 25,
    addMore: true,
    allowDuplicates: false,
    extension : ["png", "gif"],
    uploadFile: {
            url: "ajax/upload.php",
            data: {},
            type: 'POST',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data, el){
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Success</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });

                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(el){
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-error\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-minus-circle\"></i> Error</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            },
            statusCode: null,
            onProgress: null,
            onComplete: null
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first result is `JSON` output and the other one returns an `array` of the response.

To achieve the JSON result you need to specify in your JS

`dataType: JSON`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The value you're seeing is the JSON you got from the server after it has been converted to a JavaScript object (and then converted to a string for displaying). If you want to convert it back into JSON and display that, you can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`.

That said, you probably want the data as a JavaScript object, because it is much easier to work with. You could, for example, use the value `data.metas.size` to perform calculations involving the size of the uploaded file (try: `console.log(data.metas.size2 + '(' + data.metas.size + ' bytes)');`). You cannot do this with the JSON representation: it is just a string.